# Disable Horizontal Scroll in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design

I'm working with a tall, narrow document in Photoshop, and I'm using a trackpad. Is there any way I can lock horizontal scrolling so that when I use my trackpad to scroll, it only moves up/down?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: What OS and laptop are you using? Older Mac's without a multi-touch trackpad [can disable horizontal scrolling system wide](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3448).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not within Photoshop I'm afraid. However, the <kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys do exactly what you are asking, plus you can make them go left right if you hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd> key too.

Comment: I don't have these keys on my laptop, but I bet I can find a way to configure function keys for it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Are you on a MacBook? You can use [fn] + [Arrow] instead for Page Up, Page Down, Page Left, Page Right.